# Webpack dev server "before" functionality

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server, create-react-app

I'm working on an ejected Create React App project, and looking at the docs on webpack dev server, they seem a little bare: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-before

but I'm trying to see if it's possible to do something like:

```
before(app){
  // read cookie for user session
  // send user ID in cookie to external API
  // retrieve user object from API
  // attach user object to response, to be _somehow_ accessed via the React app client side
}
```

I know this is pseudo code, but I'm very unclear about what *exactly* you can do within this middleware, in terms of hooking into Create React App's rendering of the index.html and aforementioned client-side React app

In the docs, it says you could define a route handler, like so:

`app.get('/some/path', function(req, res) {  }`

but I don't feel like that's going to be useful, as you wouldn't then be able to hook back into Webpack dev server's rendering process?

Answer (score 8):

You can try adding this in your webpack config file, and practically you can use it as a mock server. Here is an example of how I configured mine and hope it helps.

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true,
    before:(app) => {
        app.post('/user/login', function(req, res, next) {
            res.json({success: true})
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: Can we use this config property to set the custom response headers? I can try but asking before hand.

Comment: for me this just returns: Cannot GET /user/login

Comment: @EugenKonkov The config above only sets up a `POST` route. Your error shows you're trying `GET`.

Comment: please add a link to the API docs

Answer (score 4):

In Webpack 5 you can get this goodness by configuring [`devServer.onBeforeSetupMiddleware`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveronbeforesetupmiddleware).
Angies' answer applies to Webpack 4 [`devServer.before`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverbefore) configurations.